# Changing mouse follower in response to mouse movement direction

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I'm trying to make a mouse follower change its image depending on which direction its moving to catch up with the mouse (eg. a pokemon sprite turning then moving forward). This is what I have so far but it's not working. **What am I doing wrong?** (Also, I'm using tumblr so this has slightly different syntax than ordinary javascrpit.)

```
var x=ox=400;
var y=oy=300;
foll=document.getElementById('follower');
document.onmousemove=function(e) {
    y=e.clientY;
    x=e.clientX;
    if (y!=oy || x!=ox) {
        foll.style.left=parseInt(foll.style.left)+(y-oy)+'px';
        foll.style.top=parseInt(foll.style.top)+(x-ox)+'px';
        var q=Math.ceil(((Math.atan((y-oy)/(x-ox)))*(180/Math.PI))/45);
```

this nasty math equation (above) is supposed to get the angle between the old place of the mouse and the new place and then put it in terms of eight directions around the follower.

```
        if (q==1 || q==8) {foll.source = {image:Follower Right};} //RIGHT
        if (q==2 || q==3) {foll.source = {image:Follower Up};} //UP
        if (q==4 || q==5) {foll.source = {image:Follower Left};} //LEFT
        if (q==6 || q==7) {foll.source = {image:Follower Down};} //DOWN
        ox=x;
        oy=y;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @bcdan I'm asking what's wrong with the code I have because it isn't working, and how I can fix it. I'm an amateur at Java

Comment: btw, Java and JavaScript are completely different things...

Comment: @diligar I've stuck your code in a jsfiddle here; https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/c8px6jtf/ it's throwing an error for the foll.source = {image: Follower Right}, I am guessing this needs to be coded as js, but at least this is a start.

Answer (score 0):

OK this could be off, but it kind of works.

Instead of setting an image source for each cursor I have passed a class based on the direction and merely changed the cursor properties via css (this should be faster than using an image source).

So the code looks like this:

```
var x=ox=400;
var y=oy=300;
foll=document.getElementById('follower');
document.onmousemove=function(e) {
    y=e.clientY;
    x=e.clientX;
    if (y!=oy || x!=ox) {
        foll.style.left=parseInt(foll.style.left)+(y-oy)+'px';
        foll.style.top=parseInt(foll.style.top)+(x-ox)+'px';
        var q=Math.ceil(((Math.atan((y-oy)/(x-ox)))*(180/Math.PI))/45);
        if (q==1 || q==8) {foll.className = 'cursorR'}; //RIGHT
        if (q==2 || q==3) {foll.className = 'cursorU'}; //UP
        if (q==4 || q==5) {foll.className = 'cursorL'}; //LEFT
        if (q==6 || q==7) {foll.className = 'cursorD'}; //DOWN
        ox=x;
        oy=y;
    }
}
```

And then four classes which correspond to the cursor you wish to set:

```
.cursorR {
    cursor: e-resize;
}
.cursorU {
    cursor: n-resize;
}
.cursorL {
    cursor: w-resize;
}
.cursorD {
    cursor: s-resize;
}
```

I have [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/c8px6jtf/1/)

Only it seems that two of the if statements are evaluating to true so you only ever see cursor right and cursor up.

Where did you obtain the original js code?

For the cursor reference see [mdsn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) (you can pass in custom urls to an image if you wish).

Comment: When I run this in tumblr, I get this error: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null] on this line: [foll.style.left=parseInt(foll.style.left)+(y-oy)+'px';]

Comment: I think you need some extra parantheses:  `foll.style.left=parseInt((foll.style.left)+(y-oy))+'px' ` although using your current code that is returning 0px